# How to open Primefaces Dialog kept inside a component?

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I'm trying to build a component that uses a dialog for some operations, I tried to follow Primefaces show case and it works fine when the dialog was inside the "client project" but when I moved it to another project, a framework where it is supposed to be I started getting a nullpointer exception every time I call it due to the .xhml file is not in the "client side" anymore.

Here is goes some code to show you:

my dialog called showClients.xhtml (just a simple example to not bother you with business logic)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Cars</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 90%;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:outputLabel value="TESTE" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

And here I try to call it from a ManagedBean:

```
    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("contentHeight", 320);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("showClients", options, null);
```

And here is what I got:

```
1:44:24,047 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(DialogNavigationHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can somebody help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll now need to tell JSF where to find the component relative to the WebContext.  So if your dialog showClients.xhtml file sits in a folder such as WebContent/resources/myapp/mydialog then you'll call

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/resources/myapp/mydialog/showClients", options, null);
```